# dplyr: Find mean for each bin by groups

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to understand dplyr. I am splitting values in my data frame by group, bins and by sign, and I am trying to get a mean value for each group/bin/sign combination. I would like to output a data frame with these counts per each group/bin/sign combination, and the total numbers per each group. I think I have it but sometimes I get different values in base R compared to the output of ddplyr. Am I doing this correctly? It is also very contorted...is there a more direct way?

```
library(ggplot2)
df <-  data.frame(
id = sample(LETTERS[1:3], 100, replace=TRUE),
tobin = rnorm(1000),
value = rnorm(1000)
)
df$tobin[sample(nrow(df), 10)]=0

df$bin = cut_interval(abs(df$tobin), length=1)
df$sign = ifelse(df$tobin==0, "NULL", ifelse(df$tobin>0, "-", "+"))


# Find mean of value by group, bin, and sign using dplyr
library(dplyr)
res <- df %>% group_by(id, bin, sign) %>%
        summarise(Num = length(bin), value=mean(value,na.rm=TRUE))

        res %>% group_by(id) %>%
                summarise(total= sum(Num))
            res=data.frame(res)
            total=data.frame(total)
            res$total = total[match(res$id, total$id),"total"]            

res[res$id=="A" & res$bin=="[0,1]" & res$sign=="NULL",]

# Check in base R if mean by group, bin, and sign is correct # Sometimes not?
groupA = df[df$id=="A" & df$bin=="[0,1]" & df$sign=="NULL",]
mean(groupA$value, na.rm=T)
```

I am going crazy because it doesn't work on my data, and this command just repeats the mean of the whole dataset:

```
ddply(df, .(id, bin, sign), summarize, mean = mean(value,na.rm=TRUE))
```

Where mean is equal to mean(value,na.rm=TRUE), completely ignoring the grouping...All the groups are factors, and the value is numeric...

This however works:

```
with(df, aggregate(df$value, by = list(id, bin, sign), FUN = function(x) c(mean(x))))
```

Please help me..

Comment: Looks like you're using `magrittr` too, the line `res <- df %<>% ...` has two assignments in it because `%<>%` assigns and pipes. Probably you just want a regular pipe `%>%` there. As-is, you're updating `df` as well as `res` when you run that code.

Comment: what's `cut_interval()` ?

Comment: Sorry, the cut_interval is from ggplot2... It still does not work this way, I get the same averages for all bins...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be flailing a bit. You've got correct code, then you've got extra code.

Starting from a fresh R session and defining your data, then

```
library(dplyr)
res <- df %>% group_by(id, bin, sign) %>%
        summarise(Num = n(), value = mean(value,na.rm=TRUE))
```

The above code is from your question, but I replaced `length(bin)` with the built-in `dplyr::n()` function. The above code accurately gives the group-wise averages:

```
head(res)
#   id   bin sign Num       value
# 1  A [0,1]    - 122 -0.08330338
# 2  A [0,1]    + 111  0.11394381
# 3  A [0,1] NULL   2  0.75232462
# 4  A (1,2]    -  54 -0.09236725
# 5  A (1,2]    +  45  0.20581095
# 6  A (2,3]    -  12 -0.08998771
```

Jumping ahead to your last couple lines in the code block:

```
groupA = df[df$id=="A" & df$bin=="[0, 1]" & df$sign=="NULL", ]
# mean(groupA$value, na.rm=T)
# [1] 0.7523246
```

Which matches the 3rd line of the above results. So you did it, it works fine!

The rest of your code is confused:

```
res %>% group_by(id) %>%
                summarise(total= sum(Num))
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with this, but you don't assign it to anything so it is run but not saved.

As for your `ddply` attempt:

```
ddply(df, .(id, bin, sign), summarize, mean = mean(value,na.rm=TRUE))
```

You'll notice that if you have `dplyr` loaded and then load the `plyr` library, there's a message that:

> You have loaded plyr after dplyr - this is likely to cause problems.
>   If you need functions from both plyr and dplyr, please load plyr first, then dplyr:
>   library(plyr); library(dplyr)

Do not ignore this warning! My guess is this happened, you ignored it, and that's part of the source of your troubles. Probably you don't need `plyr` at all, but if you do, load it **before** `dplyr`!